# jsoup status code on login page redirect

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to do a test request to a server to determine whether if my session id is still valid or not:

```
Connection.Response testRequest = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                        .method(Method.GET)
                        .cookie(SESSION_KEY, sessionId)
                        .execute();
```

If it's still valid, I will access the page that I'm after. However, if the `sessionId` isn't valid, I will get redirected to a sign in page instead.

My problem is that if I check the `testRequest.statusCode()`, it'll say `200` a.k.a. "OK", regardless if it was a valid session id or not.

In case I use an invalid session, I get redirected (status code `302`) to the login page. But jsoup only seems to capture the page/status after I'm redirected.

Is there any way to get the "first" status code? Or should I use `HttpClient` for this instead of jsoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution in case someone's interested:

```
Connection.Response testRequest = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                    .method(Method.GET)
                    .followRedirects(false) // <-- did the trick
                    .cookie(SESSION_KEY, sessionId)
                    .execute();
```